# Azure Function v1 error System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs

Tags: .net, azure-functions

I created an azure function and everything is working fine. But as soon as i add another project reference I am getting this build error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Attribute.InternalGetAttributeUsage(Type type)
   at System.Attribute.InternalParamGetCustomAttributes(ParameterInfo param, Type type, Boolean inherit)
   at MakeFunctionJson.ParameterInfoExtensions.GetDisabledAttribute(ParameterInfo parameterInfo)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.GetDisabled(MethodInfo method)
   at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.HasUnsuportedAttributes(MethodInfo method, String& error)
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.<GenerateFunctions>d__9.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryGenerateFunctionJsons()
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryRun()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Error generating functions metadata     C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.24\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets  41
```

My csproject file below.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v1</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\xxxx\vvv.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Also see below the csproject file for the reference project(propitiatory information masked).

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>vvv</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>vvv</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU</Platforms>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Nuget & Assembly Information -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Version>2018.09.11.1</Version>
    <Company>xxx</Company>
    <Copyright>© 2018 xxx</Copyright>
    <Title>xxx</Title>
    <PackageTags>xxx net462</PackageTags>
    <Authors>xxx</Authors>
    <Description>vvv (ASP.Net 4.6.2)</Description>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>0</WarningLevel>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <WarningsAsErrors />
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>0</WarningLevel>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>

    <Reference Include="EntityFramework">
      <HintPath>Plugins\EntityFramework\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer">
      <HintPath>Plugins\EntityFramework\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This issue is happening only when this project reference is added. Otherwise there is no build error. I am not able to find out what dependent component is causing this issue.

Comment: Looks like some dependency load failure due to conflict. Enable FusionLog and post the output. "To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1."

Comment: Hi, please show the .csproj files of your function and other projects.you are refer to.

Comment: Hi @BowmanZhu, added csproj files in the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your .NET sdk version of you project to the same in referenced project so that the azure.webjobs version will be the same. This error is due to the conflict in version in your projects. You can update your .NET sdk using Manage NuGet package option